# RegionPlot3D error: Must be a boolean function

Tags: 3d, wolfram-mathematica, calculus

RegionPlot3D[x^(2/3) + y^(2/3) + z^(2/3) <= 1.5^(2/3), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]

I am trying to graph this 3D inequality but I keep on getting the same errors. Mainly

> LessEqual::nord: Invalid comparison with -2.3811+4.12419 I attempted.
>
> RegionPlot3D::boolf: x^(2/3)+y^(2/3)+z^(2/3)<=1.31037 must be a Boolean function.
>
> General::stop: Further output of RegionPlot3D::boolf will be suppressed during this calculation.

I feel like what I am doing is completely correct but I guess not. Any help from y'all would be very appreciated.

Comment: If you limit the plot to x,y,z>=0 it plots just fine. But if you look at `N[(-1)^(2/3)]` or any other negative number to the 2/3 power you will see the result is a complex number and `<=` doesn't give you a true or false result when comparing two numbers, at least one of which is complex. That is what the error message is telling you. Can you think of a different way of defining your region to plot?

Comment: Wow this worked! I just ended up putting Abs[] around x, y & z. Thanks you.